# no ability to enter numbers or special chars in input

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

The below works for the most part; however numbers can still be entered via two ways: **'copy paste'** and also from **browser cache/suggestions,** i.e. if your browser is giving you suggestions from your history to fill the input. Numbers can still be achieved in those two ways.

Anyway to eliminate the ability for numbers being entered in the field completely?

```
<input type="text" data-value-field="value" name="styleName" onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" />
```

Comment: Have you considered turning off autocompletion? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: Also, you can still modify the value of the input by going into Developer Tools and changing the `value` attribute on the `<input>`. A possible solution could be to use `setInterval()` to regularly check and cleanse the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```js
abc.oninput = function() {
  const val = this
  if (/[0-9~`!@#$%\^&*()+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?¬£.]+/.test(this.value)) {
const i = this.value.match(/[0-9~`!@#$%\^&*()+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?¬£.]+/g)
if (i !== null) {
  i.map(function(el) {
    val.value = val.value.replace(el, '')
  })
}
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-value-field="value" name="styleName" id="abc" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`onpaste="return false"` is used to cancel the paste event.

`autocomplete="off"` is used to prevent auto-completion.

`setInterval(() => { ... }, 100);` is used to regularly check the input and remove any numbers or special characters. *This prevents the user from being able to use `input.value = " ... "` in the Developer console to set the input's value to something invalid, as the input will automatically be corrected.*

```js
const input = document.getElementById('cleanse');

setInterval(() => {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
}, 100);
```

```html
<input type="text" data-value-field="value" name="styleName" onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" id="cleanse" />
```